# Adding jobs to pool dynamically or whenever a core is freed up

Tags: python, multiprocessing

PS : Run on Ubuntu with python

I am trying to solve a bunch of routing problems (Travelling Salesman). The set of customers can change every day so I take random samples of the network and solve each of those samples. With sufficient samples, I will be able to get an estimate of the expected average cost. So i would like to keep generating a new sample and solve the sample until the sample average converges and doesn't fluctuate much (represented below using a CONVERGED() which returns True if converged).

So, I wanted to run these samples in parallel to speed up computation, where a new sample is generated and solved IFF the cost has not converged. So my code(v1) looked like below.

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
q = manager.Queue()    
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count() + 2)

while not <CONVERGED()>:
    job = pool.apply_async(<FUNCTION TO CALCULATE OUTPUT>, <ARGUMENTS>))
    job.get()
```

I eventually realized that when job.get() is called, it does not run till all CPUs are busy but instead wait till finishing all outstanding jobs (i.e. 1) before continuing with the while loop. So, I tweaked the above to run a batch of 100 each time as showed below in code(v2).

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
q = manager.Queue()    
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count() + 2)

while not <CONVERGED()>:
    jobs = []
    for i in range(100):
        jobs.append(pool.apply_async(<FUNCTION TO CALCULATE OUTPUT>, <ARGUMENTS>))
        for job in jobs:
            job.get()
```

This worked decently but due to the nature of the problem, the time solve each sample can vary drastically. So if one of the 100 took EXTREMELY long to run (not uncommon), all 99 runs would finish and it would wait for the last slow run to finish before starting another batch of 100.

### ***Ask***

Is it possible to modify it such that i dont need to set a batch size or it constantly just keeps adding runs/samples when a previous run/sample has ended and the average has not converged?

***Edit 1***

There are no outputs for each run and the input/argument to each of these is just a simple integer which acts as a random seed. They just write to a file/generate a new file each run. <CONVERGED()> loops through those files/written results to determine if convergence has been achieved.

***Edit 2*** - Follow up/My implementation issues to BooBoo's solution

Some of the details probably dont matter, but in case thats the cause I am erring on the side of caution. I had tried to use a global variable (like converged) to track convergence before but that never worked. When the variable is updated, the outer loop does not register the change and does not stop. If I were to use the magic function within a callback, it works **FLAWLESSLY**. So there are 2 things i am trying to understand. 1) Is there a benefit to the callback function as opposed to having it inside the function as i have it?  2) Why does my version not update the global variable?

```
def MC(args1, args2, args3):
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()    
    pool = BoundedQueueProcessPool(multiprocessing.cpu_count() + 2)

    # Activating Listener
    pool.apply_async(listener, (q, csv_name, message, data, csv_col)) # this is just a process that i am using to read and write to a file as needed
    count = 0

    global _CONVERGED
    while not _CONVERGED and count <= iterlimit:
        print(count, '-', _CONVERGED)
        count += 1  
        pool.apply_async(mc_call, (data, target, q, count, csv_name))

    pool.close()
    q.put([-2]) # this kills the listener
    pool.join()
        
    return None


def mc_call(data: MDVRPI, target: str, q: int, seed:float, csv_name:str):

    global _CONVERGED

    # TODO : Below could be put as a callback. Any benefit?!
    if magic_function_to_calc_if_converged():
        _CONVERGED = True
        return None

    gen_data = generate_data(...)
    run_output = run_generated_data(...)
    
    q.put([run_output]) # gives output to listener to write to file

    return None



if __name__ == '__main__':

    _CONVERGED = False # Flag for convergence


    MC(Args1, Args2, Args3)
    return 0
```

***Edit 3*** - Information on listener

The listener function is simply a dedicated process with a queue that writes to file. Each individual process (routing problem) will do some computation and submit its results to the queue. The listener function then appends these lines to the csv file and flush(). This way the file is updated and if read by any of the other processes, it will be updated with the latest runs (or close enough). Below is the code. I have hidden some of the function arguments for clarify sake.

```
def listener (q, csv_name, message, data, csv_col):
    '''
    Listens for results from each new run and prints it to file. -1 indicates convergence & -2 indicates end of run (i.e. close file)
    '''

        file = open(csv_name, "w")
        file.write(platform.node() + ', ,'+ message +'\n')
        file.write(','.join(csv_col) + '\n')
        file.write(','.join(['0' for i in range(__main__.csv_col)]) + '\n')
        file.flush()
        

        while True:
            m = q.get()
            if m['status'] == -1:
                # print('Converged')
                pass
            elif m['status'] == -2:
                # print('End of run')
                break
            
            file.write(','.join([str(i) for i in [m['seed'],m['cost'], m['time'], m['solverstatus'], *m['demands']]]) + '\n')
            
            file.flush()
    file.close()
    return
```

Comment: Just to clarify: When you execute `job.get()` you are waiting for one specific submitted "job" or "task" to complete and will block until it does. Consequently, (1) You are effectively doing any multiprocessing at all and (2) Because after every time you call `pool.apply_async` you are appending the returned `AsyncResult` instance to `job` and then immediately calling `get()` on *every* `job` in `jobs`, you are calling `get()` on "jobs" you have already called `get()` on. You need to outdent the `for job in jobs:` block to have more than one job run in parallel.

Comment: I am currently using v2. But v2 only runs 100 (or the batch size) in parallel each time. my issue/question is, if 99 of the 100 runs are finished and the last one is really slow, can I start more parallel runs before waiting for the slow 100th run to finish?

Comment: Did you look at my answer at all?

Comment: When you declare a variable global, each process actually has its own copy in its own address space of that variable so when it is modified the change is not reflected in any other process (strictly speaking, under Linux a child process inherits the address space from the parent process and therefore its global variables but when such a variable is modified then a separate copy is made, i.e. this is copy-on-write semantics). You can pass a  single `multiprocessing.Value` instance, which resides in shared memory,  to your processes and then updates will be visible to all processes.

Comment: See [this example](https://ideone.com/1QfOV1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my comment posted on your question. It's not entirely clear what your "listener" is attempting to do because you have posted incomplete code. It's also not clear, for the same reason, how arguments for any given job submission is generated. But I will attempt to give you some ideas that may be useful to you.

Let's supposed that you had a generator function that can generate arguments for your , which we will arbitrarily name `calculate`:

```py
def generate_arguments():
    while True:
        # Generate next set of arguments:
        ... # Code omitted
        yield arg1, arg2, arg3
```

Now we can use a special subclass of `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` I called `BoundedQueuePool` for which you can repeatedly submit jobs with `apply_async` but will throttle job submission so that the number of total jobs sitting on the pool's input job queue does not by default exceed twice the number of pool processes. We continue to generate arguments and submit new jobs until a callback function that gets invoked whenever a new result has been generated. This function will detect whether the results have converged or not and (1) Set the global flag `converged` to True so that no more jobs are submitted and (2) A call to `terminate` on the pool to kill any submitted jobs that have not yet completed. This happens implicitly when the `with BoundedQueueProcessPool(8) as pool:` exits.

Putting it all together:

```py
import multiprocessing.pool
import multiprocessing

class BoundedQueuePool:
    def __init__(self, limit, semaphore_type):
        self._semaphore = semaphore_type(limit)

    def release(self, result, callback=None):
        self._semaphore.release()
        if callback:
            callback(result)

    def apply_async(self, func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None, error_callback=None):
        self._semaphore.acquire()
        callback_fn = self.release if callback is None else lambda result: self.release(result, callback=callback)
        error_callback_fn = self.release if error_callback is None else lambda result: self.release(result, callback=callback)
        return super().apply_async(func, args, kwds, callback=callback_fn, error_callback=error_callback_fn)

class BoundedQueueProcessPool(BoundedQueuePool, multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def __init__(self, *args, max_waiting_tasks=None, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.pool.Pool.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if max_waiting_tasks is None:
            max_waiting_tasks = self._processes
        elif max_waiting_tasks < 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid negative max_waiting_tasks value: {max_waiting_tasks}')
        limit = self._processes + max_waiting_tasks
        BoundedQueuePool.__init__(self, limit, multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore)


if __name__ == '__main__': # Required for Windows
    def generate_arguments():
        while True:
            # Generate next set of arguments:
            ... # Code omitted
            yield arg1, arg2, arg3

    converged = False

    def my_callback(result):
        global converged
        ... # Code omitted
        # We have determined that the results have converged:
        converged = True

    with BoundedQueueProcessPool(8) as pool:
        for arg1, arg2, arg3 in generate_arguments():
            if converged:
                break
            pool.apply_async(calculate, args=(arg1, arg2, arg3), callback=my_callback)
```

**Explanation**

Suppose you have a large number of tasks to submit to a processing pool via method `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async` and that you can generate these tasks much faster than pool can process each task and generate a result. You would have the situation where the input task queue of the pool, which holds tasks waiting to be processed, will continue to grow and consume memory. This is not an issue if the number of tasks that will eventually be put on queue is not that great and the amount of data (the arguments to the worker function(s)) is not so large and you have adequate memory. But take the example of where you have a multi-gigabyte text file where each line of that file represents another task to be submitted. If the main process goes into a loop reading the file line by line submitting each one to the pool, you will soon exhaust all of memory. Or take the case where you have potentially an unlimited number of tasks you are submitting. In your example you might be in a loop generating tasks for as long as it takes until a certain result is produced.

In these cases you would like a method to "throttle" the submission of tasks. Let's assume the pool as N processes. Then there is really no need for the input queue to have more N * 2 tasks on the input queue at any point in time. I specify N * 2 instead of N just to ensure that when a pool process becomes idle there is a task on the queue ready to be fetched and executed rather than having to wait for the main process to generate another task. But whether it is N or N * 2 tasks or a larger number really isn't anything to worry about for the purposes of this discussion.

So class `BoundedQueueProcessPool`, a specialization of `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`, supports a modified version of method `apply_async`. "Under the covers" it creates a semaphore initialized to size N * 2 (by default) where N is the pool size. When you call `apply_async` the code first does an `acquire` method call on the semaphore. You can do this N * 2 times before the semaphore count goes to 0 and a subsequent call will block. However, whenever a task completes, thus making a pool process idle and ready to take a new task from the input queue, a call to `release` is made on the semaphore thus allowing a blocked `apply_async` call to acquire the semaphore and complete the submission of a new task.

To be able to support both "bounded queue-size" multiprocessing pools *and* bounded queue-size multithreading pools, much of the aforementioned logic resides in a parent class `BoundedQueuePool`, which is the actual direct child of `Pool` and `BoundedQueueProcessPool` is then a child of `BoundedQueuePool`. This make it easy to create another class `BoundedQueueThreadPool` (not shown) that is a child of `BoundedQueuePool` to handle bounded queue-size multithreading pools.

The important point of the code is that the main process is in a loop  calling `apply_async` with an inexhaustible collection of tasks it will submit until a certain result is detected. So as to not allow the queue size to grow unwieldly large, we throttle task submission so that the queue size never exceeds a certain amount.

It appears that the solution posted by Ahmed AEK is also trying to keep the pool size limited in a different way by first submitting a fixed number of tasks and then only waiting until a task completes submitting another task. The difference with my solution is that the logic is encapsulated in a way that makes it (in my opinion) more readily reusable in other solutions you might have. All you have to do is change the class you are using for the pool and no other code changes are required.

Comment: I can roughly follow the code in main. But I could not follow whats happening in the 2 classes above. Could you help clarify some of it?

Comment: I have updated the answer adding an explanation.

Comment: What? Neither of the posted solutions answered your question satisfactorily?

Comment: No. I was testing out what you had suggested. Trying to make sure the issues are not due to bugs i introduced before asking again. I will shortly post an update

Comment: Hi Booboo, I just added an edit to my initial question with the update/issues. I was unable to show my code here properly. I managed to make it work perfectly. I just had 2 questions which I thought would help in my understanding of the whole setup! PS: Your explanation on the code was really helpful to understand it too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a callback in `apply_async` so that each time a job is done, another job is submitted, and when converged you just terminate the pool.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
import random
import threading

def converged():
    global result
    return result >= 10


def computation():
    time.sleep(random.random()*3)
    print("done calculation")
    return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)  # set to what you want

    min_jobs = 20  # initial number of tasks to be submitted
    result = 0  # to calculate convergence
    done_event = threading.Event()  # to be notified of convergence

    def callback_func(res):
        global result
        result += res  # update convergence condition

        if converged():
            print("done")
            pool.terminate()
            done_event.set()  # wake up main thread
        else:  # replace the that task just ended
            pool.apply_async(computation,
                             callback=callback_func,
                             error_callback=my_error_callback)

    def my_error_callback(res):  # for catastrophic failures
        print("a task failed, PANIC !!!!!!")
        pool.terminate()
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exception(res)
        done_event.set()

    for i in range(min_jobs):
        pool.apply_async(computation,
                         callback=callback_func,
                         error_callback=my_error_callback)

    done_event.wait()  # sleep till woken up
```

note that `done_event` is used as "just wait until i am terminated from the callback"

```
done calculation
done calculation
done calculation
done calculation
done calculation
done calculation
done calculation
done calculation
done calculation
done calculation
done
```

personally "sleep till woken up" is very dangerous in production, so i'd put  a timeout in it (of a few hours maybe ?), and after the timeout just terminate the pool and raise an error, so that you don't end up with a machine that's hanging forever,

you also might want to wrap your `callback_func` body in a try/except, because if it throws then your PC will hang forever too... but at least you will see the error on your screen.